# How to pass file name while importing files

Tags: r

Hi I have folder which contains multiple .CSV files ,How to pass file name in new column while importing CSV file,

E.g
File_1.csv,File_2.csv,file_1000.csv

```
Name     value     file_name
A         43        File_1
B         223       File_1
C         345       File_2
D         43        File_2
.          .           .
Z         56        File_1000
```

I have written a code to import file multiple file and appends one below the other.

```
setwd("Path/")
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
library(data.table)
raw = rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

But unable to pass file name for each set of rows for validation purpose

Thanks in advance